# JS constant inside another constant with ethers.js

Tags: javascript, constants, ethers.js

I'm using ethers.js to encode in ABI a IPFS hash provided by a text box on an html page, in order to save it on the blockchain. To do that, I have an input id'd as "ipfs-hash", called with a variable. An then, another variable which encodes it. Nevertheless, this last step doen't work, and when I try to take the hash from a variable the code breaks. However, the second variable seems to work fine when I change

```
INPUTHASH
```

variable for an actual value.

```
'Qm...'
```

```
const INPUTHASH =  $('#ipfs-hash').html //Direct input from text box                
const ABIOUTPUT = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode([ 'string' ], [ INPUTHASH ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was a problem with Jquery.js, not ethers.js.

```
const INPUTHASH = $('#ipfs-hash').val();
```